# Start unit when AC adaptor is plugged

Tags: linux, laptop, systemd, acpi

I want systemd to start a unit file when the AC adaptor of my laptop is plugged. Likewise, I want to stop the same unit when the adaptor is unplugged. Maybe attaching the unit file to the unevent? I don't really know how that stuff works.

**Background**

I have a number of maintenance scripts run nightly by fcron. I don't wan the scripts to run if AC is not connected. At this moment all the scripts check the AC status and bail out if not on AC.

```
if [ `cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online` -eq 0 ]
then
   exit 0
fi
```

This works, however for fcron the job was run and will bot run until the next night. If at a later moment of the night I will connect the power, I actually want the jobs to be run. (if within the timeframe set in crontab)

So, since fcron is only running these kind of scripts, I would prefer much more to stop fcron when the AC is unplugged and start it after plugging in.

The cleanest solution wins (less script=better)

Comment: This response might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87750/130000

Comment: Suggested link applies to ACPID, which I don't have installed. And probably ACPID is listening to uevents, which are first processed by udev. Which again is part of systemd. Also, that solution requires additional scripting, while the goal of this conquest is to use less scripting.